# Execute a Jquery file from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a .Js file that I want to called to executed inside the php code to fix table headers, I dont know how to call the functions from PHP.

Here is my PHP code:

```
echo "<div class=\"wrapper\">";
echo "<table class=\"blue\"><thead><tr><th>ITS No</th><th>Date</th>            <th>Cell</th><th>Shift</th><th>Requestor</th><th>Category</th><th>Issue</th>";
echo "<th>Action</th><th>Action Owner</th><th>Aging</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th><th>Completed Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
```

I created table header and then I want to use jquery function to modify and fixed the header

JS code:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.fixMe = function() {
return this.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $t_fixed;

  function init() {
    $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
    $t_fixed = $this.clone();
    $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
    resizeFixed();
  }

  function resizeFixed() {
    $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
      $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
    });
  }

  function scrollFixed() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
      tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
      tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
    if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
      $t_fixed.hide();
    else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
      $t_fixed.show();
  }
  $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
  $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
  init();
});
};
  })(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
$("table").fixMe();
$(".up").click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: 0
}, 2000);
});
});
```

Comment: `echo '<script src="fixTableHeaders.js"></script>';`... ?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code is executed when it's linked into the html page. So you can just echo the < script > tag and it executes.

Answer (score 1):

Just echo the script call.

```
echo "<script src='/myscript.js'></script>"; // comment to make a valid edit
```